# Awaiting approval participant status message template

Tags: civievent, system-workflow-messages, waitlist

When requiring participant approval, it sends this email message. I would have thought it would have been in the system workflow messages under message templates. It is not. So where do I find this in core?

[image]

Also while configuring the online registration, it let's you customize the approval message, but I do not see where this is actually showing to end users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is within the `Events - Registration Confirmation and Receipt (on-line)` template.